# This field is required. Django

Tags: python, django-forms

Need some help. One of my form is not responding.
When i field all the information in the form and click submit button.  the error "This field is required"  appears in the "NOMBRE" field for no reason. And don't let me save my object.

[image]

models.py

```
class Cliente(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    edad   = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    telefono = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    correo = models.EmailField(max_length=254)
```

views.py

```
class AgendarCreate(SuccessMessageMixin, CreateView):
    model = Cliente
    form_class = AgendarClienteForm
    template_name = 'main_web/agendar.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('agendar')
    success_message = "Client was created successfully"
```

forms.py

```
class AgendarClienteForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Cliente

        fields = [
            'nombre',
            'edad',
            'telefono',
            'correo',
        ]

        labels = {
            'nombre' : 'Nombre:',
            'edad' : 'Edad:',
            'telefono' : 'Teléfono:',
            'correo' : 'Correo electrónico:',
        }

        widgets = {
            'nombre' : forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'caja'}),
            'edad' : forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'caja'}),
            'telefono' : forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'caja'}),
            'correo' : forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'caja'}),
        }
```

HTML

```
<form id="agendar_forma" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <p class="titulo_cotizar">Datos de contacto:</p>
  {{ form.non_field_errors }}

  {{ form.nombre.errors }}
  <p class="forma">{{ form.nombre.label }}</p>
  <p class="caja">{{ form.nombre }}</p>

  {{ form.edad.errors }}
  <p class="forma">Edad:</p>
  <p class="caja">{{ form.edad }}</p>

  {{ form.telefono.errors }}
  <p class="forma">Teléfono:</p>
  <p class="caja">{{ form.telefono }}</p>

  {{ form.correo.errors }}
  <p class="forma">Correo electrónico:</p>
  <p class="caja">{{ form.correo }}</p>

  <button type="submit" class="caja3">Agendar mi cita</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Set it as optional in forms. Currently it is required by leaving out the [`blank` parameter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#blank).

> If True, the field is allowed to be blank. Default is False.

```
nombre = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True)
```

Comment: But in my case the "Nombre" (name) field is required, i insert some text in it, but when i click in the submit button the error appear anyway.

Comment: That was unclear from the question. The screenshot shows a blank Nombre field with everything else filled out.

Comment: Sorry, but yes i put text in all the fields and when i submit the form, the text from the Nombre field disappears and shows the text like the photo. I don't know what is happening because i have other form with the same inputs, and this works fine. Already tried to change the field to another name, thinking is the variable overlapping but is not make sense because i call the form correctly in my views.py.  By the moment my solution is change the class model to a function model.